# linear transformation of orthogonal vector space on subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $F$. If $W$ is a subspace
of $V$, prove that the orthogonal projection of $V$ on $W$ is an idempotent linear transformation of $V$ into $W$.

I have tried this:

Consider $T:V\to W$, then 
$$
T(ax+by) = \frac{\{ax+by,w\}}{\{w,w\}}w = a\frac{\{x,w\}}{\{w,w\}}w + b\frac{\{y,w\}}{\{w,w\}}w=aT(x)+bT(y)
$$
where $ax+by\in V$ , $w\in W$, $a,b\in F$, and $\{m,n\}$ represent orthogonal projection of $m$ on $n$.

But to prove idempotent, *i.e.* $T^2 = T$, I do not get right result.Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here's a [reference for MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For any $v \in V$, try expressing $v$ in terms of a basis that spans $W$ and a basis that spans $W^T$. ($W^T$ is the orthogonal complement of $W$.)

Comment: @Anlamk , but how V$ = W$ + $W$ ^{T} help me in proving